# ¿Como realizar una suma de un rango de números en C++?

Tags: c++

Debo hacer una suma de rango pero sin incluir a los números que determinan el rango. Aquí está la instrucción completa:

"Calcular la suma de los números enteros comprendidos entre m y n, sin incluirlos a ellos. Use como valores de prueba:

m = 12 y n = 21. Resultado = 132

m = 5 y n = -3. Resultado = 7"

Hasta ahora este es el código que he intentado, pero toma en cuenta los 2 valores (m y n) y necesito que no lo haga:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n1,n2,suma;

    cout<<"Escriba el primer numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<" Escriba el segundo numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;

    suma=((n2 - n1 +1) * (n1 +n2)) / 2;

    cout<<"La suma de los numeros comprendidos entre "<<n1<<" y "<<n2<<" es:"<<suma<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

¡Saludos y gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: ¡Hola!. Básicamente mi pregunta es: ¿Cual es la manera de sumar los números comprendidos en un rango (ejemplo: los números entre 5 y 10) sin incluir el 5 y 10 en la suma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el primer `if` sabemos que no hay números entre los dos dígitos, por lo tanto imprimimos directamente que la suma es cero, en el segundo `if` verificamos que `n1` no sea mayor a `n2`, si `n1` es mayor a `n2`, solo invertimos los valores para que `n2` siempre se nuestro número limite y `n1` nuestro número de inicio:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n1,n2,suma,aux;


    cout<<"Escriba el primer numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<" Escriba el segundo numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;

    if(n1==n2){
        cout << "La suma es 0";
        return 0;
    }else if(n1 > n2){
        aux = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = aux;
    }

    n1++; //Aumentamos en uno el valor inicial
    n2--; //Disminuimos en uno el valor final
    suma=((n2 - n1 +1) * (n1 +n2)) / 2;

    cout<<"La suma de los numeros comprendidos entre "<<n1-1<<" y "<<n2+1<<" es:"<<suma<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas:

1. La fórmula no es correcta si no quieres incluir los extremos.
2. Esa fórmula solo funciona para enteros positivos, por lo tanto tienes que reformularlo para cuando alguno de los parámetros sea negativo. Además es necesario que n1 sea menor que n2.

Son ya muchas suposiciones o casos que tienes que tener en cuenta para utilizar esa fórmula. Lo más sencillo sería iterar y solo comparar para saber cual de los dos número es mayor

**Sin distinguir casos:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n1,n2;
    int suma = 0;

    cout<<"Escriba el primer numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<" Escriba el segundo numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;

    if (n1 > n2){
      for (int i=n1-1 ; i>n2 ; i--)
        suma+=i;
    }else{
      for (int i=n2-1 ; i>n1; i--)
        suma+=i;
    }

    cout<<"La suma de los numeros comprendidos entre "<<n1<<" y "<<n2<<" es:"<<suma<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sirvió perfecto y gracias por marcar los errores. ¡Saludos!

Comment: De nada! Recuerda que es importante votar( https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote ) si te han sido de ayuda las respuestas de tamalk o la mia. Saludos!

Comment: Lo iba a hacer pero soy nuevo y me dice que necesito mínimo 15 de reputación... :(